# One car speaker problem

Tags: audio, wiring, speakers

Front driver speaker not working. The only thing I have to test it is a cheap lil 12v tester (1 with light in handle of a screw driver). Is it possible to test with this. When I ground the tester and touch each terminal separately the light does come on albeit a Kim flickery but never the less the light is on. I have a feeling this is not a viable way to test car speakers. Any suggestions

Comment: If you want to test the speaker you could find and old stereo that has external speakers and connect that. You should at least be able to prove if the speaker works. You could also connect and old car speaker to the existing wire and prove that the stereo and wiring work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can get some speaker wire directly from the radio to the speaker - if it works fine one possibility is the speaker wiring is damaged in the joint between car body and door.